# Single Sign On Webapplication Java

Tags: java, web-applications, single-sign-on

I´m developing an web application in java that is called from a pre-existent portal.
I need to check if the user is authenticated in this portal to show my application.
I don´t have access to his database to check the user and pass again.

I don´t know what the portal can pass to me that garantees that the user is 
authenticated.
Maybe a token, or i can check the domain.  I´m not sure how to do this.

I´ve searched to use spring security, but i didn´t find a solution yet. 
Some sites say to integrate it with cas, but i don´t have cas here.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: To clarify, is you app going to run as a portlet within the portal? If this is the case, which portal server software will your portlet be running within?

Comment: Could you provide more info about what your pre-existent portal looks like (JSR-168/286, perhaps) ? Also, how is your application called from this portal (are you developing portlets, maybe) ?

Comment: it is not a portlet. It´s an full jsf application that the portal will only link. I need to only open this application through this link and with the user authenticated.

Comment: This is not a complete question. You failed to provide information on the *existing* security solution you need to plug-in too. Anyone can make a random guess or suggestion based off what you asked currently. For example here is my solution for you - 'Query the SMUSER id from the HTTP session and validate it against your MySQL database'. Helpful right?

Comment: Hi Perception. I don´t know how is the existing security solution. I only need some ideas about how can i check if the request is coming from this portal and if the user is authenticated. How? Maybe an parameter like a token. I only want to know some ideas.

Comment: Maybe James Ward post can show and idea of how to do this:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/463609/Tomcat/Implementing-Single-Sign

Comment: @axdmoraes - I understand where you're coming from. What I was trying to convey in my comment was that it will be infinitely better to investigate with your portal team, how to plug into their security layer, rather than having complete strangers on SO try to guess what you might have and how to plug it into your solution. There are literally dozens of ways to do what your asking, but nobody can provide an intelligent option without more information about your portal.

Answer (score 0):

Web applications can use container based security.

You need to hook this mechanism up with the portal which may, or may not, be relatively easy.  The portal must expose its security mechanism.

How to actually *do* this, depends on your actual container.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to answer the question here. If *other portal* links to your application and requires you to identify *other portal's* user, it must specify how this could  work. You all need to specify an interface between the two applications which describes how exactly user identification has to happen. "*other portal*" people should tell you what they support as well as what they recommend...